Boot Custom Kernel with UEFI in QEMU
I'm trying to boot a custom kernel on QEMU using UEFI. This is for an OS that I'm writing. When I run this command, I'm brought into the UEFI shell. I may be wrong, but I think that if everything is setup correctly, QEMU should boot into the kernel instead of the UEFI shell. I tried using the boot manager to run the kernel and changing the boot order but did not have any luck.
I suspect that my kernel is in the wrong format. When I run file myKernel.img in Ubuntu, I get this output:
myKernel.img: OpenPGP Secret Key

I've read about UEFI stubs online, but I think that's for Linux kernels only. Here's how I build myKernel.img:
aarch64-linux-gnu-objcopy -O binary myKernel.elf myKernel.img

And here's the QEMU command:
qemu-system-aarch64 \
-cpu cortex-a76 \
-machine virt,kernel=myKernel.img  \
-display gtk,show-tabs=on -device ramfb -serial vc \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,unit=0,file=firmware/uefi/AARCH64_OVMF_CODE.fd,readonly=on \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,unit=1,file=firmware/uefi/AARCH64_OVMF_VARS.fd

I appreciate any suggestions or advice! Also, let me know if this isn't the right place for this question. I initially asked this on Stack Overflow, but it didn't fit that site.

How did you build your kernel? What kind of entrypoint does it have? Although "EFI stub" is usually used in Linux context, the concept behind it (a specific boot protocol that the firmware expects from the kernel) broadly applies to anything that boots through EFI.

The kernel is built as an .elf file using aarch64-linux-gnu-ld. Then aarch64-linux-gnu-objcopy -O binary is used on it. The entry point is at _start. A linker script sets the entry point of the kernel. I think the entry point needed is based on the QEMU setup and the fact that Arm64 architecture is being used?
So, does the header of the kernel file give the specific boot protocol that the firmware expects?

I don't think it does – although I can't find Qemu's -machine kernel= documented anywhere, so I'm not sure whether it expects to be given a Linux kernel (like -kernel does) or whether it expects an EFI executable file (like UEFI firmware would normally expect), but I'm about 80% sure that it won't accept a bare "load and jump" image, especially with no information like load address specified for it (as I understand it, -O binary explicitly strips away all such information that the .elf might have had).

Thanks for the information! I'll keep working on it and post an update if I figure it out or get stuck on a specific thing. Running qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt,help, the kernel option says this: kernel=<string> - Linux kernel image file

Very surface-level answer since I don't really have sufficiently deep knowledge:

When I run file myKernel.img in Ubuntu, I get this output:

That's what you usually get when the file isn't in any specific format other than "raw blob of machine code", i.e. it has no recognizable header and the file command ends up showing its closest guess. (It makes most of its decisions based on a few leading bytes, and the ARM machine code probably happens to coincide with a valid OpenPGP header.)

the kernel option says this: kernel=<string> - Linux kernel image file

Then it most likely expects the image to have a Linux-like header that indicates which base address the image should be loaded at, where the entry point is, etc. Your -O binary output does not have any such information.
(It's similar in concept to the ELF header which you are currently removing, although highly Linux-specific and platform-dependent; e.g. Linux on x86 would use a more complex handshake than it does on AArch64.)
Although when it's used in combination with UEFI, I'd almost expect this option to require an EFI-format image file rather than a Linux-kernel file.

I've read about UEFI stubs online, but I think that's for Linux kernels only.

Only the stub part (i.e. the concept of gluing a bootloader directly onto the kernel image) is Linux-specific, but the overall problem it solves is UEFI-specific.
UEFI cannot directly accept raw "load at X and jump to Y" images like what your objcopy -O binary produces, as it doesn't know where to load it and where the entry point is. Instead, it expects to be provided an .efi file in the PE/COFF format (aka literally an .exe file by another name) which has this information.
Traditionally this would have been a dedicated bootloader (e.g. grubx64.efi or elilo.efi) which then knows how to launch a Linux kernel, and that applies equally to any OS that boots through UEFI – e.g. Windows starts via winload.efi – and the only Linux-specific part is the combining of the two functions into one dual-faced "vmlinuz but with PE/COFF makeup" .efi file.
So either your build output itself is wrapped into a PE/COFF header so that it becomes a valid .efi file for UEFI to run (possibly using elf2efi), or you need to use an intermediary such as GRUB or U-Boot (i.e. which already is a valid .efi program in itself) to load it.
